# What is the terminology for 1st line of main function?

Tags: c++, c, terminology

As shown highlighted in attached snapshot,starting line of main function,i know that it is starting point of main function but what is the proper term for it?can we call it function declaration line?
[image]

Comment: Is *function signature* the term your looking for?

Comment: `main` is also called the entry point .. ?

Comment: Are you looking for:  the *definition* of the function `main`.

Comment: I don't think there is a proper lane. The closest thing might be the function declaration? But it certainly isn't the declaration **line**. That declaration can easily be broken up into multiple line, and the definition can also be part of the first line. C++ doesn't care much about lines.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for... `main` is the **entry-point**. It's also a **function-definition** (though this is more generic for _any_ function definition)

Comment: Informally, I call it the "head line" of the main function.  That terminology is by no means widespread, it is idiosyncratic that I use when conversationally referring to it.  I also call the `if (expr) ...` part of the if statement the "head line" of the `if` statement.

Comment: There is no specific standard name for it. In the the C and C++ grammars, it is composed of multiple parts, and nothing in the grammar distinguishes the `int main()` part from the rest of it. You could call it the part of the function definition without the body. But why would you want to? That is not a rhetorical question; if you are looking for terminology, presumably you want to communicate something to somebody. What? The purpose of the communication could be illuminating about a good phrasing for communicating it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about C, but here are some snippets from the C++23 draft:

[`dcl.fct.def`/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#general-3)

Example 1: A simple example of a complete function definition is

```
int max(int a, int b, int c) {
  int m = (a > b) ? a : b;
  return (m > c) ? m : c;
}
```

Here `int` is the ***decl-specifier-seq***; `max(int a, int b, int c)` is the **declarator**; { /* ... */ } is the function-body. — end example]

So, in `int main()` we get that `int` is the *decl-specifier-seq* and `main()` is the *declarator*.

We also have another example (sorry for only finding *examples*) [`dcl.fct`/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#9):

[Example 5: The declaration

```
int fseek(FILE*, long, int);
```

**declares** a function taking three arguments of the specified types, and returning `int` (`[dcl.type]`). — end example]

(while not formal), I deduce that the combination of the *decl-specifier-seq* and the *declarator* makes the `int main()` part a ***declaration***.

Comment: @IanAbbott I see. That's the danger of using multiple language tags. I didn't notice it had a C tag (I don't subscribe to C questions).

Comment: Correction to my (deleted) comment: The C standard uses slightly different terminology: `int` is the *declaration-specifiers*, `max(int a, int b, int c)` is the *declarator*, and `{ ... }` is the *compound-statement*.

Comment: @IanAbbott Got it! I will edit and make it clear that my answer is only applicable to C++.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int main()
```

in the function definition (that is at the same time a function declaration) is called the **function declarator** that has the return type (type specifier) `int`.

That is this code snippet in whole

```
int main()
{
    //...
}
```

is a function declaration that introduce the identifier `main` in the file scope.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function declarator of main that does not accept arguments shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: `main()` is the declarator. `int` is a specifier and is not part of the declarator.

Answer (score 0):

There are two terms in C and C++ that share a common usage, and unfortunately often gets confused with each other. The terms are ***declaration*** and ***definition***.

A declaration is telling the compiler that something (a "name") exists, somewhere in the program. A definition is the implementation of the thing that was declared.

For functions, you can have a declaration and definition at the same time.

For example lets say your program have a function named `foo`, taking one `int` argument and returning a `int` value. It can be declared as:

```
int foo(int arg);
```

This declaration of the function is also known as declaring the *prototype* of the function. You need to have this declaration before you call the function, or the compiler won't know that it exist. After the declaration it's possible to call the function, the compiler don't need to see the full implementation of the function, only the declaration.

Then we have the definition, where we implement the function:

```
int foo(int arg)
{
    return arg * 2;
}
```

Now lets take another function `bar` which takes no arguments and returns no value. It has no previous declaration, only a definition:

```
void bar(void)
{
    // Does something here...
}
```

But because there's no existing declaration before the definition, the definition is *also* is the declaration.

---

Also note that there is a big difference between C and C++ when it comes to function declarations.

In C a function taking no arguments *must* use the argument type `void`. Not specifying any arguments:

```
void some_function();
```

actually declares the function `some_function` as taking an indeterminate number of arguments of indeterminate type. The C compiler will then fill in the missing arguments details when the first call is made, or when it finds another declaration (or definition) that specifies the arguments.

In C++ such a declaration declares the function as taking *no* arguments.

This is only *one* difference between C and C++, and the reason why many of us here don't like questions being tabbed with both languages, or the term "C/C++".

Comment: This answer does not speak to the question asked (what is a term for a specific part of a function definition), fails to mention that a definition is a declaration, and implies that only functions can have a declaration and a definition at the same time (other types of identifiers can be defined and declared at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, function declaration means are just declaring the function name, its arguments and its return type.
e.g.

```
int foo(int x, int y);  ==> Function declaration ends with semicolon ;
```

Function definition means you are actually defining the functionality.
e.g.

```
int foo(int x, int y){
      return x+y;
}  ==> Function definition enclosed within curly braces { }
```

And the given main() function is function definition.

In general terms, for conventional purpose may be you can call the first line of a function definition as "function header".

And the entire code within the curly braces { } of the function definition as "function body".